# Positive Input Ventilation (PIV) suitability for loft with high relative humidity

Tags: ventilation, uk, condensation

I live in the UK in a cold 1890s stone walled house which has a condensation issue (partly brought on by lifestyle choice and party due to previous "remedial" works that limit the natural ventilation of the house). I have heard a lot about Positive Input Ventilation systems and have even had them recommended to me.

Over the last few weeks I have tracked the relative humidity in the house and loft (attic) space before making any decisions and logged an average relative humidity of 83% in the livable area of the house (this is wet) but a relative humidity of 90% in the loft (attic). I am aware why this probably is (warm moist air rising and leaching into the loft space/plus inadequate ventilation in the loft) but wanted to understand if a PIV would work under these conditions.

In other words does a PIV require the air from the loft to be a lower relative humidity than the living space for it to work?

Comment: Why not just run a dehumidifier?  I live in Western Washington State which can be quite humid  as a rains a lot.  I pull about 1.5 gallons a day out of my house. This isn't an answer, just a comment and a question to try and fully understand your situation.

Comment: Thanks it's a fair observation. We have used a dehumidifier but we find that we require 3 or 4 to drop the humidity low enough across the whole house. Also emptying this many becomes a bit of a chore.

Comment: Wow,   I have 2, one for the house and another for the shop.  Both have provisions for connecting a hose to drain the condensate.  That's practical for the one in the shop bc I just run the hose under the garage door.  Doesn't work for the house one though, no practical path, but, get this,   we collect the condensate into old gallon milk jugs that my wife uses to water her plants!

Comment: @AWGIS where is all that water coming from? If you've run a dehumidifier for a while and it's staying that humid, it seems possible you've got moisture getting in via another path.

Comment: @KMJ sorry for clarification those readings are without running the dehumidifier. The dehumidifier does decrease humidity levels but not significantly across the whole house using one.

Comment: @AWGIS how much does it extract? If it pulls out a gallon in a day and you only have three people in the house, you have water coming in from somewhere else.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm on the same page, what do you consider a dehumidifier? I wonder if the standard American dehumidifiers versus what we use here in the UK might be wildly different! In the UK I consider a dehumidifier a relatively small free-standing device that can remove between 10 and 20 litres per day?